# How to prevent direct templateurl navigation in browser when using ui-router in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Following is my code:

```
var app = angular
            .module('moviesApp', ['ui.router'])
            .config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {          
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/SignIn');          
                $stateProvider
                    .state("SignIn", {
                        url: "/SignIn",
                        templateUrl: "Pages/SignIn.html"
                    })
                    .state("SignUp", {
                        url: "/SignUp",
                        templateUrl: "Pages/SignUp.html"
                    }); 
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            });
```

When I load the state - '*/SignIn*' it loads the contents of 'Pages/SignIn.html' in *ui-view* as expected. Similarly, when I load the other state - '*/SignUp*' it loads the contents of 'Pages/SignUp.html' in *ui-view*.

**What is my requirement?**

I want 'Pages/SignIn.html' or 'Pages/SignUp.html' to be loaded only through states in ui-view. They should not be loaded through direct URL navigation in browser.

In other words, when I type '*/Pages/SignIn.html*' directly in the browser's address bar, it should be redirected to the state '*/SignIn*'.

The contents of html files under 'Pages' folder should not get displayed over direct url navigation.

How can I achieve this? Please advise.

Comment: Why do you care? Why would anyone go to /Pages/SignIn.html, and what's the problem of doing so and just getting the template? You can embed the htm templates in the JS bundle if you want to, but I don't really understand why you want to do what you're asking.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet,

Thank you for the response.

Is it not a problem if the users view the templates which would look unformatted when loaded directly? Of course, there are no functional issues. Nobody will load them directly. I just wanted to know if this is how everyone deals with the templates when ui-router is used. Please advise.

Comment: Well, if someone is tech-savvy enough to analyze the network traffic to detect what the page loads using AJAX and then loads a template directly, he/she shouldn't be surprised to get an HTML template, and should not complain that your site isn't working as expected. Just like if he/she loads a JSON resource directly and gets JSON back, or a CSS file, or a JS file. This is a non-problem, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Your explanation was very clear. I'm marking your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent it from showing in the address bar use name instead of url

```
    $stateProvider.state('default', {
        url:'',
        templateUrl: ctx + '/jsp/home/dashboard.jsp'
    }).state({
        name:'/test',
        templateUrl: ctx + '/jsp/home/testview.jsp'
    });
```

In the html page give as below

```
<a ui-sref="test">test view</a></li>
```